# Regex to merge all the lines of all paragraphs, while keeping those paragraphs separated

Tags: regex

I have the following text :

```
Paragraph1

Paragraph2
Paragraph2
Paragraph2
Paragraph2

Paragraph3
Paragraph3

Paragraph4
```

I want to merge all the lines of each paragraph, while keeping those paragraphs separated.

For the time being I go through 3 successive steps

1) I first use `\n(?!\n)` replaced by a space

The result is :

```
 Paragraph1
 Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2
 Paragraph3 Paragraph3
 Paragraph4
```

I merged all the lines of each paragraph, but I am left with 2 problems :

2) I have to remove the blanks at the beginning of the paragraphs

I then use `^\s` replaced by nothing, which gives :

```
Paragraph1
Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2
Paragraph3 Paragraph3
Paragraph4
```

3) I must then insert blank lines between the "merged paragraphs, replacing `\n` by `\n\n`, which gives at long last the result I want :

```
Paragraph1

Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2

Paragraph3 Paragraph3

Paragraph4
```

Is it possible to replace this 3-steps contraption by ONE regex ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the paragraphs always start and end with word characters, you can use

```
\b\n\b
```

and replace with the empty string.

That is, newlines will be removed if the position before the newline *and* the position after the newline are both word boundaries. Otherwise, if at least one is not a word boundary, that will indicate that you're between paragraphs.

https://regex101.com/r/jsfzph/2

Answer (score 0):

If we replace newlines which are not preceded by a newline, nor followed by a newline, with a single space, we can get the output you want.  Consider the following regex pattern:

```
(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)
```

and then replace with a single space.  Here is a working Java code snippet.

```
String input = "Paragraph1\n\nParagraph2\nParagraph2\nParagraph2\nParagraph2\n\nParagraph3\nParagraph3\n\nParagraph4";
input = input.replaceAll("(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)", " ");
System.out.println(input);

Paragraph1

Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2 Paragraph2

Paragraph3 Paragraph3

Paragraph4
```

### Demo

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I chose CertainPerformance's solution because, in fact, all my paragraphs start and end with word characters (which I should have mentioned). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert not an empty line `(?!^$)`. Then assert that what follows is a newline followed by not a whitespace character `(?=\n\S)`. If that is the case, then match a newline `\n` and replace that with a whitespace.

This would also match if your paragraph is `Paragraph3 (test)`

`(?!^$)(?=\n\S)\n`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/waP1ze/1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, which, of course, works (and the test on Paragraph3 is important), but I have already chosen CertainPerformance's solution. Nevertheless, I shall keep this one in mind (and your explanation is very useful for me to better understand the regex). Thanks again